# After upgrade to TFS 2015, user names are incorrectly shown in some drop down fields in work items

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem

We have just upgraded from TFS 2013 to 2015 Update 2 and have come across a problem in the work item definitions.

Using the field Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Discipline we have some odd behaviour. In the work item, clicking on the drop-down for this field we have the allowed values shown, as defined in the ALLOWEDVALUES rule for this field. This is as expected.

However, we're also seeing a number of user names shown in the drop down list. It's as if the rule VALIDUSER has been used in the Field Definition. But it has not.

We're using the Discipline field in several work items and we have the same behaviour in all of them.

Anyone else had this kind of odd behaviour?

New information below - this is the defintion of the field in the work item.

```
<FIELD name="Discipline" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Discipline" type="String" reportable="dimension">
    <HELPTEXT>The discipline to which the bug belongs</HELPTEXT>
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="Analysis" />
      <LISTITEM value="Development" />
      <LISTITEM value="Test" />
      <LISTITEM value="User Education" />
      <LISTITEM value="User Experience" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  </FIELD>
```

And this is the field definition shown by witadmin.

```
  Field: Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Discipline
  Name: Discipline
  Type: String
  Use: it (Bug, Task, Incident, Admin)
  Indexed: False
  Reportable As: dimension
  Synchronizes Identity Name Changes: False
```

Comment: Please share the one of the work item definitions that use Discipline field? And run command witadmin listfields /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /n:Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Discipline and post the output?

Comment: I added the extra information above.

Comment: According to the field definition, you have two custom work items type "Incident" and "Admin", what have you modified to them? Does this issue happen on both VS and Web Access?

Comment: Yes, we have also Incident and Admin work items, which are pretty much a copy of the Task, with one or two minor changes. These were all working correctly before we switched to TFS 2015. The issue happens only in the web interface, using VS there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since your issue only happens on Web Portal, please try to clean the cache files on TFS AT machine:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Web Services\_tfs_data
```

and

```
C:\TfsData\ApplicationTier\_fileCache
```

After cleaned, click **Start** and select **Run**… to open the dialog box, then input **iisreset.exe** and click **OK**, wait it run completely.

Comment: Ok, I didn't find the folder _tfs_data under that path. Only place I found it, under Microsoft Team Foundation Server **14.0**, was in the TFSJobAgent folder & there it was empty. The other folder _fileCache I cleaned out, then did the IISReset. Made no difference unfortunately. It's tempting to drop the field and recreate it....

Comment: All your team members are experiencing this issue? Kindly share us whether recreating this field would fix this issue.